# PHP OOP with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, oop

ok Guys have a big trouble and cann't anderstand what is going on.
Please help.

first of all I have a DB connection class:

```
    private $localhost = DB_LOCALHOST;
    private $db = DB_DATABASE;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $password = DB_PASSWORD;
    protected $link ;


    function __construct()
      {

       $this->link = mysql_connect($this->localhost,$this->user,$this->password) or die(mysql_error()."<br/>".mysql_errno());
       mysql_query("SET NAMES ".DB_CHARSET , $this->link) or die(mysql_error()."<br/>".mysql_errno());
       mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->link)or die(mysql_error()."<br/>".mysql_errno());
           if($this->link===false)
           die("Didn't connect to DB");            

       }

       function sql_query($q)
       {    
          $r = mysql_query($q, $this->link) or die ("DATABASE ERROR! Please, contact the administrator.".mysql_error().);
          return $r;
       }

        function __destruct()
        {
           mysql_close($this->link);
        }

      }
```

then I use it in another one in two different functions:

```
     function del_meal($id_meal)
     {
         $db_s = new DBConnect();
     $db_s->sql_query("DELETE FROM `pictures` WHERE `id_target` = '{$id_meal}' AND `type` = 'meal';");
     $db_s->sql_query("DELETE FROM `meal_ingredient` WHERE `id_meal` = '{$id_meal}';"); 
     $db_s->sql_query("DELETE FROM `meal` WHERE `id_meal` = '{$id_meal}';"); 
     unset($db_s);
     $pictures = $this->select_pictures($id_meal,'meal');
         if(count($pictures)>0)
         {
           foreach($pictures as $pic)
           {
            if(file_exists("./pictures/meal/{$pic}"))
             {
               unlink("./pictures/meal/{$pic}");
               unlink("./pictures/meal/thumb/{$pic}");
             }
           }
         }
     }

    function del_category($id_category)
    {
       $db = new DBConnect();
       $id_category = $db->safe_var($id_category);
       $q = $db->sql_query("SELECT * FROM `meal` WHERE `id_category` ='{$id_category}' ");
    while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
        $this->del_meal($res['id_meal']);
    }
    $db->sql_query("DELETE FROM `meal_category` WHERE `id_category` = '{$id_category}' ");
    unset($db);
    }
```

ok - here is safe_var()

```
   function safe_var($var)
  {
      $var = stripslashes($var);
      $var = trim($var);
      $var = strip_tags($var);
      $var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
      $var = htmlspecialchars($var);
      $var = nl2br($var);

      return $var;
  }
```

So - when I use just del meal function - everything is fine - but when I use del category - 
I get "Warning: mysql_query(): 7 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in DBConnect.php on line 33
DATABASE ERROR! Please, contact the administrator."

What can be the reason. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You're overwriting $id_category

Comment: You checked out `mysqli()`? OOP MySQL out of the box - http://php.net/mysqli

Comment: @Jason McCeary sorry - but server - where the site is - doesn't support it :(

Comment: I don't see your definition of safe_var()

Comment: @Bryan - forget about safe_var() - it isn't a very important. It doesn't work without it

Comment: Have you checked that your constructor is even executing? If your host is still on PHP4, auto-execution of __construct is not supported

Comment: The reason I ask is that apparently somewhere the value of id_category is being set to `$this->link` variable in the DB class.

Comment: @Marc B: If he was running this on PHP4, it would parse error on the private/public member declarations.

Comment: @Gavryschuk: You're right. It's not important :)

Comment: @webbiedave I ment in this case

Comment: @Gavryschuk: I know. I was agreeing with you :)

Comment: well, it's obvious that somewhere $this->link being overwritten by an integer(probably id_category). I also spotted that $link is declared with a public scope. Is this necessary for anything? Also applying a try-catch with a print-out of the backtrace would be very helpful for you.

Comment: public is not necessary - I already changed it to protected.

Comment: +1 to bryan for pointing out that `$this->link` is being overwritten somewhere.  Check your code, I feel like we're not seeing the whole picture here.  I think you're overwriting link.

Comment: Yes! thank everybody for help - the issue was in select_pictures(). I forgot to unset the object there and $this->link was overwritten. The problem is resolved!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like SkippyChalmers said, you need a single Database instance.

```
function db($config)
{
    static $db = NULL;
    if($db === NULL)
    {
        $db = new DBConnect($config);
    }
    return $db;
}

// db()->sql_query(...);
```

However, I recommend that [you switch to PDO](https://github.com/Xeoncross/1kb-PHP-MVC-Framework/blob/master/classes/db.php).

Comment: +1 agreed. Although a wrapper class rather than wrapper function? Or use of static property (accessed by a static method).

Comment: @SkippyChalmers, a wrapper class would also be a bad idea as both of these methods break Dependency Injection. However, given the level of code he is producing I opted for a simple wrapper function that seems to match the level of code he is producing. Singleton is still bad though and should only be used on very small applications where the overhead of DI isn't worth it.

Comment: @Xeoncross, interesting thoughts there. I see what you mean, and yes - actually agree. For the level and purposes of this application a simple wrapper function makes sense. I wasn't meaning actually implementing the singleton pattern though, I meant using a static property and then calling a static getter method on it from within an instantiated object. It's late and I'm doubting myself, but would that not ensure the persistence of the connection across multiple instantiations?

Comment: @SkippyChalmers, you could do a static method or an individual function. However, I find `db()->query()` nicer to type than `DB::get_instance()->query()`. Plus, if you extend the DB class you would have to go back through your application and replace all the DB::get_instance() with My_DB::get_instance() (or alter the DB::get_instance() method to return a My_DB object).

Comment: Too right :) I think I got mixed up and wanted to do $db = new db(); and then store the link resource as a static property which could be accessed via a static method, using the self:: operator.

Comment: I have some site - Where I have already used PDO extension. And after the Hoster updated PHP to 5.3.6 - my admin panel was unavailable as it had a PDO error - that I couldn't to fix without Hoster supprot. Their support was so slow. So - question: Why should I use PDO if it can destroy my site for a while? I can Use my own class for Mysql connections insted and everything will work fine :)

Comment: @Gravryschuk, Sorry to hear you had a bad experience with that. PDO does require that you have the pdo_mysql or pdo_pgsql (mysql or postgresql) extensions installed to work. But after building database classes with mysql, mysqli, and PDO - PDO is the clear winner for modern applications (everyone is using it now).

Answer (score 2):

```
if($link===false)
```

Should be:

```
if($this->link===false)
```

Should it not?

Also, you can do better than this! Design it so the DB connection is persistent across all uses of the class. One new connection for every query is not good practice. Good start though. As Jason McCreary said, use mysqli, or PDO or something out of the box. Lot's of third party libraries out there too. Have you considered a data-mapper solution? This is a good start though!

EDIT:
I'm going to recommend using a dependency injection container to properly persist the DB connection.

Comment: Yes - Ofcourse should be $this->link. And also You are right about a new connection for each query - I will look in this side.

Comment: Ensure error reporting is on. I might need to take a closer look but from this far away, it looks like you're not actually connecting successfully.

Comment: Okay... sorry @Gavryshuk, I've made a bit of a mess of this by not actually reading your code properly. Can you modify the sql_query method to do a var_dump of $this->link? Can you also remove as much uncessary code from your example as possible? (After testing that the remaining code still produces the error)

Answer (score 0):

I council you, to `Extend` database class, or make DB class instance 1 time in construct.

Example with Extend:

```
class Anything Extends Database {
///and here you can use DB methods as $this->sql_query...
}
```

Second way is:

```
class Anything {

   private $db;

   public function __construct() {
      $this->db = new DBConnect();
      //then use db as $this->db->sql_query in the class with this same instance.
   }
}
```

I think these are right ways.

OR Try to edit your constructor. Try this:

```
function __construct()
      {

       $this->link = mysql_connect($this->localhost,$this->user,$this->password) or die(mysql_error()."<br/>".mysql_errno());
       mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->link)or die(mysql_error()."<br/>".mysql_errno());
       mysql_query("SET NAMES ".DB_CHARSET , $this->link) or die(mysql_error()."<br/>".mysql_errno());
           if($this->link===false)
           die("Didn't connect to DB");            

       }
```

Comment: Yes - should $this->link - but after I fixed it doesn't change anything

Comment: Sorry, don't see how you've actually achieved anything by extending a db class or implementing a wrapper class, so -1 for now. You've not actually made use of a persistent connection in your wrapper class either.